# AngularJS - how to add to an object using forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="BooksController as bookCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="bookCtrl.add()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.rating">
        <input type="text" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.type">
        <input type="text" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.author">
        <input type="hidden" value="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-stack-1x" ng-model="bookCtrl.book.picture">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is my JS:

```
.controller("BooksController", ['BooksService', function(BooksService) {
    var self = this;
    self.getBooks = function() {
      return BooksService.getBooks();
   } 
    self.add = function(book) {
        alert(book.name);
        BooksService.add(book);
    };


}])

.factory("BooksService", [function() {
    var books = {
        1: {
            name: "k",
            review: "k",
            rating: 2,
            type: "k",
            author: "k",
            picture: "fa fa-keyboard-o fa-stack-1x",
            },
        2: {
            name: "b",
            review: "b",
            rating: 4,
            type: "b",
            author: "b",
            picture: "fa fa-code fa-stack-1x",
        }
    }

    return {
        getBooks: function() {
            return books;
        },
        add: function(book) {
            books[4] = book;
        }
    };
}])
```

The issue here is, when I fill out the information for the form and try to add a book, the book is undefined. I tried to do

```
alert(book.name);
```

and it gave an error saying

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
```

How come it is undefined? What I want to do is take the information provided in the form and add a book to the "books" object.

Comment: you haven't passed book object in ' <form ng-submit="bookCtrl.add()">' or you can access it like 'self.book.name' in add method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form ng-submit="bookCtrl.add(bookCtrl.book)">
```

Or this:

```
self.add = function() {
    alert(self.book.name);
    BooksService.add(self.book);};
```

Comment: okay, thanks. I commented on the other replies as well but I'll ask the question here too just in case: Do you know if there is a recommended approach or are both options you provided basically the exact same?

Comment: both are basically same. But if you pass argument in function (here in add function), it can be used as generic method. and you can pass any object in it. if you don't pass, it will always consider self.book

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. Either use `this.book` controller instance:

```
self.add = function() {
    alert(this.book.name);
    BooksService.add(this.book);
};
```

or pass book object from HTML to controller method:

```
<form ng-submit="bookCtrl.add(bookCtrl.book)">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Pick what ever you prefer. I would say the first one is cleaner no need to pass anything since it's already available.

Comment: okay, thanks. I commented on the other reply as well but I'll ask the question here too just in case: Is there is a recommended approach or are both options you provided basically the exact same?

Comment: In your simple case they produce the same result, so it's more matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment correctly suggests you haven't passed the book object in the `ng-submit="bookCtrl.add()"`.

You can reference the `bookCtrl.book` object directly from the `add` function:

```
self.add = function() {
    alert(self.book.name);
    BooksService.add(self.book);
};
```

Comment: Right, thanks. Do you know if there is a recommended approach or are both options you provided basically the exact same? (using self.book or passing the book object in bookCtrl.add(bookCtrl.book) and doing self.add = function(book))?

Answer (score 0):

Change the form tag to

```
<form ng-submit="bookCtrl.add(bookCtrl.book)">
```